# Cannot get stroke on video mask to show in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am appending a mask to my mx:VideoDisplay element so that I can have rounded corners.  The mask and even a dropshadow filter work great but I cannot get the stroke of the mask (using lineStyle) to show.  Researched a ton and tried many fixes.  At my wits end.  Any help would be really appreciated.

```
            private function applyMask():void {
            myMask.graphics.clear();                
            myMask.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xFFFFFF);
            myMask.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            myMask.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 180, 156, 35);
            myMask.x = 0;
            myMask.y = 0;               

            videoMy.mask = myMask;
            videoMy.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(3)]
        }
```

later on I call the video element:

```
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="videoMy" right="10" top="10" width="240" height="196"/>
```

Comment: Try setting cacheAsBitmap to true on the video and mask

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do what you want with the mask directly-- it's a mask, so it is not drawn on, only used to mask other pixels.
What I would do is to create another child that is drawn on using the graphics calls you have above, but in a separate, normal display list sprite or some such added as an overlay of the masked VideoDisplay.  This should accomplish what you're attempting to do.